# Cannot append new line string to a file Android local storage

Tags: java, android

I am saving some csv to a file on the local android storage.I want to append new lines to existing csv file but my code  overwrites the previous data and I can see just a single line of csv text.Please guide where I am going wrong.Here is my current code.

```
private void saveLogFile(Long activityTimestamp, Long currentTime,
        Integer activityType) {
    if (activityTimestamp != null && currentTime != null
            && activityType != null) {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File myFile = new File(dir, "activity_log.csv");

        try {

            if (!myFile.exists()) {
                myFile.createNewFile();
            }
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
                //List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                //data.add(new String[] { activityTimestamp.toString(),currentTime.toString(), activityType.toString() });
                String[] data={ activityTimestamp.toString(),currentTime.toString(), activityType.toString() };
                writer.writeNext(data);
                writer.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("saveLogFile", "some data is null");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chante

```
new FileWriter(myFile)
```

to

```
new FileWriter(myFile, true)
```

the second parameter is the `append` flag. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 1):

See [**Java Docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), use `FileWriter(File file, boolean append);` that is:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true));
```